# How can I send information from a web server to an Electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am in the process of building an electron which will eseentially provide "notifications" when a certain form is filled out in a certain service that is connected via oAuth2.

I am having trouble, however, finding any information about the process that (i think) will need to happen.

I am thinking...

a user submits form A from this web service

that web service CAN (not sure if this is the way to go) do a HTTP post to my server

then I was thinking that my server could send that info over to the electron app. I've looked into 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-workers', but i'm still unclear if this could help solve my problem.

Any help or even a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Isn't it easier to make the other way around? Have the app connect to the server and request data, or connect to the web server and provide a communication channel like websocket or something.

Comment: Servers can not send data to a browser (electron), only return data. so the browser must do one of two things. either poll the server every few seconds to check for update. or use a websocket.

Comment: that makes sense. I'm successfully making calls out, got oAuth2 set up and everything. Basically, I want "close to real time" notifications, but it seems like polling the server every few seconds is pretty intensive. I'll look more into websockets; never really messed around with them before. Thanks!

Comment: Socket.io is a great library to help you with the realtime side http://socket.io

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple way to do that, but this can only simply be done from the renderer process from Electron (basically your front-end),

### Use a web socket for real-time application

Web socket is a technology that enable real-time communication between server and client. The most famous is [socket.io](http://socket.io/). You can have a look at [Web Sockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) too.

### Set an interval that do an Ajax request to your server

```
var checkNotifications = function() {

    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();

    r.open("POST", "url/of/your/notifications", true);

    r.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
            alert("Success: " + r.responseText);
        };

    r.send();
}


setInterval(checkNotifications, 5000); // every 5 seconds
```

Comment: i've also talked with a few of my co-workers about this challenge and have concluded that socket.io is the way to go. Then my idea gets even tricker, because I will only want to send notifications to ONE certain person, instead of every client listening on my socket. I've definitely opened up a can of worms with this idea.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the principle of socket: a socket is client-specific: it depends of your back-end/server app, but you can totally send a notification to one specific client (it's meant for). One socket = one link between the server and the client, two sockets = two different and independant links between server and client.

Answer (score 0):

Electron is running a local node http server, but it's not a public address. Max Ogden has mentioned - I think in the "State of Electron" youtube talk - installing a "headless" electron app on a public webserver to do some service related stuff, but basically you have to have a reachable address. Do you want a desktop webserver to have a public URL?

Comment: After talking with a few of my co-workers about my challenge, I think web sockets via socket.io is the best route for my case